# In UNIX shell scripting: What does $! expand to?

Tags: unix, shell, ksh

What is the meaning for $! in shell or shell scripting? I am trying to understand a script which has the something like the following.

```
local@usr> a=1
local@usr> echo $a
1
local@usr> echo $!a
a
```

It is printing the variable back. Is it all for that? What are the other $x options we have? Few I know are $$, $*, $?. If anyone can point me to a good source, it will be helpful. BTW, This is in Sun OS 5.8, KSH.

Comment: I find it amazing that the accepted answer is built around a reference to the Bash manual, being, as it is that you specified ksh (Sun OS 5.8).

Comment: True. Back then, I did not see a difference between BASH and KSH.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The various `$…` variables are described in [Bash manual](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html#sect_03_02_05). According to the manual `$!` expands to the PID of the last process launched in background. See:

```
$ echo "Foo"
Foo
$ echo $!

$ true&
[1] 67064
$ echo $!
67064
[1]+  Done                    true
```

In `ksh` it seems to do the same.

Comment: What does that mean? I tried and I could not understand what is it?
usr> echo $!
17893
usr> false
usr> echo $!
17893

Comment: Guru, try this: sleep 120 & ; echo $1 ; ps -ef | grep $!

Comment: It's the PID of the last *background job - it won't change until you run a background job.

Comment: @paxdiablo. Great. Now, I am understanding.

Answer (score 2):

From the `ksh` man page on my system:

```
  ${!vname}
      Expands  to the name of the variable referred to by vname.  This
      will be vname except when vname is a name reference.
```

Comment: An example perhaps? Expands confuses me. :(

Comment: `man ksh` will tell you, there are too many to copy into an answer here.

Comment: This form is referred to as indirection. `a=1; b=a; echo ${!b}` results in "1"  being printed.

Comment: The shell expansion `${!var}` is not what was asked. It was `$!`.

Answer (score 1):

For the shell you are asking, ksh, use the [the ksh manual](http://www.manpages.info/sunos/ksh.1.html), and read this:

> Parameter Substitution
>        A parameter is an identifier, one or more digits, or any  of
>        the characters *, @, #, ?, -, $, and !.

It is clear that those are the accepted options $*, $@, $#, $?, $-, $$, and $!.
More could be included in the future.

---

For the parameter $!, from the manual:

> "!"   The process number  of  the  last  background  command invoked.

if you start a background process, like `sleep 60 &`, then there will be a process number for such process, and the parameter $! will print its number.

```
$ sleep 60 &
[1] 12329
$ echo "$!"
12329
```

If there is no background process in execution (as when the shell starts), the exansion is empty. It has a null value.

```
$ ksh -c 'echo $!'
```

If there is a background process, it will expand to the PID of such process:

```
$  ksh -c 'sleep 30 & echo $!'
42586
```

That is why `echo $!a` expanded to `a`. It is because there is no PID to report:

```
$  ksh -c 'echo $!a'
a
```

---

Other shells may have a different (usually pretty similar) list of expansions (a parameter with only one $ and one next character).
For example, bash recognize this `*@#?-$!0_` as "Special parameters". Search [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) for the heading "3.4.2 Special Parameters".

> Special Parameters
>          The shell treats several parameters specially.

Answer (score 0):

It gives the Process id of last backgroundjob or background function
Please go through this link below

```
http://www.well.ox.ac.uk/~johnb/comp/unix/ksh.html#specvar
```

Answer (score 0):

! is a reference operator in unix, though it is not called with that name.

It always refers to a mother process. Try typing :! in vi, it takes you to command prompt and you can execute commands as usual until exit command.

! in SQLPLUS also executes the command from the command prompt. try this in sqlplus

SQL> !ls --- this gives the list of files inthe current dir.

$! - obviously gives the process id of the current/latest process.

Comment: -1 for naming 3 out of a million other uses in totally unrelated languages or environments. `$!` has exactly one meaning in shells (which is far from obvious if one hasn't learnt it before).